# how to create map with laser scanner data of kinect

Tags: navigation, mapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to create a map with laser scanner data of kinect . i am using depthimage_tolaserscan package by running "rosrun depthimage_tolaserscan depthimage_tolaserscan image:=/camera/depth/image_raw" and i can see laser data in rviz correctly.
and i use gmapping package with "running rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping" .
when i run rviz icannot receive any map in rviz.

what's your seggestion?!

tnx.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133916/how-to-create-map-with-laser-scanner-data-of-kinect/) by [parhamso](https://answers.ros.org/users/12516/parhamso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-27**:
Do you provide odometry?

**Comment by [parhamso](https://answers.ros.org/users/12516/parhamso/) on 2014-02-27**:
yes, i tried to add odometry using trutle_tf.

**Comment by [parhamso](https://answers.ros.org/users/12516/parhamso/) on 2014-02-27**:
can u suggest me how to create map any way?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For `gmapping` you need odometry. try `hector slam` if you dont have odometry.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parhamso](https://answers.ros.org/users/12516/parhamso/) on 2014-02-28**:
how i can use "hector_slam" for creating map ?

**Comment by [sam3891](https://answers.ros.org/users/21120/sam3891/) on 2015-03-05**:
http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping